# Play Store how to publish beta version of App from Manage Releases page

Tags: android

On Google Play Developer Console, I am searching away to publish App from Beta Channel to Production Channel(Promote to Prod) On Manage Releases page, I was using APK page but

> The APK page will soon be fully replaced by the Manage Releases page.

on the following, what i was doing on APK page.
[image]

So, what is the steps to publish beta version of App on Manage Releases page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following steps:

Step one: prepare release:

1-Press Create release on Manage Release Page

2-Choose Add APK From Library

3-Select your beta version.

Step Two: Review and rollout:

if you get the follwing message:

```
This release is ready to be rolled out.
```

Press On Start rollout

Comment: Exactly! You are absolutely right. But I have the problem, every thing is fine and have Tick mark (Done), but still the "Start rollout to Production" is disabled. How to enable this.

Comment: Same problem. Everything is fine but "Start rollout to Production" is graded out.